# Suggestions of route optimization algorithms to implement in QGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, route, optimization

I need to compute routes on a QGIS project with time and distance associated. Is there any route optimization algorithm to compute routes given the points that one wants to connect?

Comment: Never used this but perhaps you could check the [v.net.salesman tool](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/v.net.salesman.html) from GRASS?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might want to use the "Road Graph plugin" for this.  It comes installed with version 2.8; just needs to be activated (checked) in the "Plugins>Manage and Install Plugins..." dialog box.

Then load in a shapefile with a road network.  Go to "Vector>RoadGraph>Settings" to choose this layer (start with default settings). You'll also see a new "Shortest Path" panel where you can enter a starting and ending point and then calculate the path.  The resulting route can be exported as a new layer, which can then be saved to another file if desired.  The attributes in the resulting file are given in both length and time, which will vary according to the settings you choose and the original information in your road layer file.